# IN и другое условие

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такой зарос

```
SELECT `id` FROM `user_service` WHERE (`service_id`='3') AND (`user_id` IN ('78', '86'))
```

Если выбирать по отдельности

```
`service_id`='3'
```

или

```
`user_id` IN ('78', '86')
```

то всё работает, но если совместить - то нет. Я так понимаю что невозможно совмещать IN с другими условиями? Как это обойти?

Comment: значит увас вместе не выполняются условия одновременно. а так напишите OR получите оба результата

Comment: Запрос требует, чтобы оба условия выполнялись для одной и той же записи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

значит у вас нет записей на одновременное условие (AND). Так напишите OR и объедините оба результата если нужно

```
SELECT `id` FROM `user_service` WHERE (`service_id`='3') OR (`user_id` IN ('78', '86'))
```

Comment: Спасибо, странно но сейчас почему-то сработало как я писал...

Comment: Правильно появились данные